# How to categorize leads in sugarCRM?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm

Hi we are using sugarCRM for our business. We have used web forms on our website to generate leads. On our website we have different types of forms to generate different types of leads e.g. Free info pack, Get a quote etc.

In sugar CRM admin panel all leads come under same leads module. I want to categorize leads as per lead type i.e. i want to create different layout for viewing different leads.

Also I want to use some fields on both leads as some fields on both forms mat same like First Name.

please suggest on same.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a lead_source in your forms. Or do you already do that? For your two examples you could create a lead and a task or a lead and a quote by creating a logic hook that uses the given lead_source.